# Nunit3 shows System.AggregateException from an assembly that does not exist with that version

Tags: nunit, nunit-3.0

This is the error:

> Message: System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred.
>   ----> System.IO.FileLoadException : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client, Version=2.1.2.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

- We are only running version 2.3.0 of Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.
- I ran a grep over the whole solution and could not find a single instance which does not use 2.3.0. or runs the version mentioned in the error
- The test itself does not have a reference to this library
- I deleted all bin folders, cleaned and rebuilded.

**Update**:
I am pretty sure the problem is not nunit. Rather it shows the symptons. How do you go about finding out where this reference is used? App.configs for example only show ranges:

```
<assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.3.0.0" newVersion="2.3.0.0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I added an app.config in the test project and in the project that the test is running in which I declared:

```
<assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.3.0.0" newVersion="2.3.0.0" />
```

Now the exception is gone. Still I don't think this is the right solution. Normally visual studio must know which assembly version is the right one without declaring an app.config every time.